# Open breakpoints window in fast way

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have c++ project in my Eclipse Oxygen2. In order to see breakpoints window I need to go to Window->Show View-> Other -> Debug-> Breakpoints

How to make this window more accessible. Is it possible somehow create shortcut in Eclipse?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default shortcut to show the *Breakpoints* view is the key sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>.

You can specify your own key binding in ***Window > Preferences: General > Keys*** for `Show View (Breakpoints)`.

Comment: is there any chance to create the new short cut in eclipse

Comment: @LovaChittumuri In _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_ filter for `Show View (Breakpoints)` and change the shortcut key in the field _Binding_. To add another shortcut key instead of changing the existing key for the same command, click _Copy Command_ before.

Comment: i wanna create new short cut - please give the suggestion.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri Go to _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_, enter `Show View (Breakpoints)` in the filter field in the top, select the _Show View (Breakpoints)_ command, click the _Copy Command_ button, set the focus into the field _Binding_, hit the new shortcut and click _Apply and Close_.

Comment: Nice.. Thank you howlger.